# Get parent name using child key in firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get parent name "170002001" by using child key "UID" in android studio. Please help. Thanks in advance :)

[image]
    String uid = user.getUid();

```
private void getdata(){
    DatabaseReference reference;
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    reference.orderByChild("UID").equalTo(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                keys = childSnapshot.getKey();
                status.setText(keys);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Edit:
Except "170002001" i am able to retrieve all parent name. :(

Comment: why this is worth a downvoting ? op is asking a question about how to use firebase

Comment: I don't immediately see what's wrong with your code (or your question btw). Is `login-e250c` the root of your database?

Comment: remember that status.setText(keys); will just place one value and not an array of values of all your parents, so thats why you are getting the last one, put a log there and see that it will bring all your keys

Comment: yep @FrankvanPuffelen.. login-e250c is the root of database.... I want to get only one parent key whose child matches the given UID... I am just a neophyte ..Help !!

Comment: In that case, I honestly don't see what's going wrong. Can you put a `System.out.println(childSnapshot.getKey())` in the loop and see what it prints?

Comment: it prints "ADMIN", "Password" and the rest two.

Comment: Tried another way to create and retrieve data...Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 5):

Place this inside your `onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)` listener

```
String parent = dataSnapshot.getKey();
```

Since firebase will manage a list of possible parent keys for that , do this

```
DatabaseReference reference;
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference();

reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String parent = childSnapshot.getKey();
            Log.i(TAG,parent);
        }
    }
```

note that reference here will be the node up above your `"170002001"` key, which is the parent of all those keys

Edit: If you want to get all UID inside each of those nodes do this

Create a POJO class to hold that user id

```
public class UserPojo {


    private String UID;

    public UserPojo(String UID) {
        this.UID = UID;
    }
    public UserPojo() {
    }


    public String getUID() {
        return UID;
    }

    public void setUID(String UID) {
        this.UID = UID;
    }


}
```

then just do the same like above

```
   reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String parent = childSnapshot.getKey();
                  UserPojo user = childSnapshot.getValue(UserPojo.class);
//get your User ID
 String user = user.getUID();
                Log.i(TAG,parent);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I can't understand why it is giving me a random ID , not that parent key

Comment: what random ID is giving you ?

Comment: YB5K68BCYLNPWJ2JSJP1CPZ5ELB2 --- i am getting this

Comment: how are you creating your parent "170002001" ?